# Beamer "progressbar" theme issue?

Tags: beamer, themes

I'm using the custom theme `progressbar` by Sylvain Bouveret. I've downloaded his 0.4x version, available at https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/presentations/beamer-slide-with-progressbar. I'm using the `demo.tex` file in his package and cut out everything but the first two slides. I get the following error:

```
! Package keyval Error: ignorestructure.bg undefined
```

I'm not sure how to fix it.

```
\documentclass[utf8, a4paper]{beamer}
\usepackage[english] {babel}
\usepackage[T1]      {fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, graphicx}
\usepackage{bibunits, tikz}

\usetheme{progressbar}

\setbeamersize
  {text margin left=1em, text margin right=1em}

\title
  [Short Title]
  {Full Title of the Presentation}

\author
  [Bruce Wayne]
  {Bruce Wayne\quad Clark Kent\\Peter Parker\quad Alan Scot}

\date
  {April 01, 2011}

\institute
  {Justice League of America}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{frame}{Overview}

  \tableofcontents

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error with an updated MikTeX system and Prgogressbar theme from [here](http://recherche.noiraudes.net/en/LaTeX.php). What system are you using.

Comment: Also works fine for texlive 2016 and pdflatex.